# Spring 4.3.0.RELEASE + Hibernate 5.2.0.Final -Error.. with root cause org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

**UPDATE**:
The error was fixed with the solution in the comments

I got this error when trying to add new row to "ecommerce" table:
It happen when i call the "this.ecommerceService.add(ecommerceEntity);" in Main Controller.

Error log:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [searcher] in context with path [/Searcher] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.searcher.entity.EcommerceEntity] with root cause
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.searcher.entity.EcommerceEntity
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:756)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:736)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:741)
    at com.searcher.dao.EcommerceImp.add(EcommerceImp.java:29)
    at com.searcher.service.EcommerceServiceImp.add(EcommerceServiceImp.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.add(Unknown Source)
    at com.searcher.controller.MainSearcherController.helloWorld(MainSearcherController.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

EcommerceEntity:

```
package com.searcher.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="ecommerce")
public class EcommerceEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name="Id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int Id;

    @Column
    private String Name;

    @Column
    private String Path;

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return Path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.Path = path;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Id = " + Id + ", Name = " + Name + ", Path = " + Path;
    }

}
```

EcommerceDAO:

```
package com.searcher.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.searcher.entity.EcommerceEntity;

@Repository
public interface EcommerceDAO {

    public void add(EcommerceEntity eCommerce);
    public void edit(EcommerceEntity eCommerce);
    public void deleteById(int id);
    public EcommerceEntity getEcommerceById(int id);
    public List<EcommerceEntity> getAllEcommerce();
}
```

EcommerceImp:

```
package com.searcher.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.searcher.entity.EcommerceEntity;

@Repository
public class EcommerceImp implements EcommerceDAO{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDAO.class);

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(EcommerceEntity eCommerce) {
        Session ss = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        ss.persist(eCommerce);
        logger.info("EcommerceEntity deleted successfully, EcommerceEntity Details="+eCommerce);
    }

    @Override
    public void edit(EcommerceEntity eCommerce) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(eCommerce);
        logger.info("EcommerceEntity updated successfully, EcommerceEntity Details="+eCommerce);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(int id) {
        EcommerceEntity ecommerceToDelete = getEcommerceById(id);
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(ecommerceToDelete);
        logger.info("EcommerceEntity deleted successfully, EcommerceEntity Details="+ecommerceToDelete);
    }

    @Override
    public EcommerceEntity getEcommerceById(int id) {
        EcommerceEntity ecommerceToReturn = (EcommerceEntity)this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(EcommerceEntity.class, id);
        logger.info("EcommerceEntity founded successfully, EcommerceEntity Details="+ecommerceToReturn);
        return ecommerceToReturn;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<EcommerceEntity> getAllEcommerce() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        List<EcommerceEntity> ecommerceList = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from ecommerce").list();
        logger.info("List<EcommerceEntity> upload successfully, List<EcommerceEntity> Details="+ecommerceList.toString());
        return ecommerceList;
    }

}
```

EcommerceService:

```
package com.searcher.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.searcher.entity.EcommerceEntity;

public interface EcommerceService {
    public void add(EcommerceEntity eCommerce);
    public void edit(EcommerceEntity eCommerce);
    public void deleteById(int id);
    public EcommerceEntity getEcommerceById(int id);
    public List<EcommerceEntity> getAllEcommerce();
}
```

EcommerceServiceImp:

```
package com.searcher.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.searcher.dao.EcommerceDAO;
import com.searcher.entity.EcommerceEntity;

@Service("ecommerceService")
public class EcommerceServiceImp implements EcommerceService{

    @Autowired
    private EcommerceDAO ecommerceDAO;

    public void setEcommerceDAO(EcommerceDAO ecommeceDAO){
        this.ecommerceDAO = ecommeceDAO;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void add(EcommerceEntity eCommerce) {

        this.ecommerceDAO.add(eCommerce);
    }

    public EcommerceDAO getEcommerceDAO() {
        return ecommerceDAO;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void edit(EcommerceEntity eCommerce) {
        this.ecommerceDAO.edit(eCommerce);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteById(int id) {
        this.ecommerceDAO.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public EcommerceEntity getEcommerceById(int id) {
        return this.ecommerceDAO.getEcommerceById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<EcommerceEntity> getAllEcommerce() {
        return (List<EcommerceEntity>)this.ecommerceDAO.getAllEcommerce();
    }
}
```

MainController:

```
package com.searcher.controller;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.searcher.entity.EcommerceEntity;
import com.searcher.service.EcommerceService;
import com.searcher.service.EcommerceServiceImp;

@Controller
public class MainSearcherController {

    @Autowired
    private EcommerceService ecommerceService;


    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "<br><div style='text-align:center;'>"
                + "<h3>********** Hello World, Spring MVC Tutorial</h3>This message is coming from MainSearcherController.java **********</div><br><br>";
        String strEndList = "";

        try {
            //ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("searcher-servlet.xml");
            //EcommerceDAO ecommerceDAO = context.getBean(EcommerceDAO.class);

            //EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory");
            //EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();


            // Creating ImageService object
            EcommerceEntity ecommerceEntity = new EcommerceEntity();

            ecommerceEntity.setId(4564564);
            ecommerceEntity.setName("Ebay");
            ecommerceEntity.setPath("www.ebay.com");

            this.ecommerceService.add(ecommerceEntity);


            //strEndList = "<br/><br/>" + ecommerceService.getAllEcommerce().toString() + "<br/><br/>";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }


        return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message + strEndList);
    }

}
```

searcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Searcher-Servlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- DataSource -->
    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SearcherDB" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
    </beans:bean>



    <!-- Hibernate 5 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.searcher.entity.EcommerceEntity</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.searcher.entity.ImageEntity</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.searcher.entity.ProductEntity</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.searcher.entity.ProductRequestEntity</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.searcher.entity.RequestEntity</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.searcher.entity.SellerEntity</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.searcher.entity.UserEntity</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- eCommerce -->
    <beans:bean id="ecommerceDAO" class="com.searcher.dao.EcommerceImp">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="ecommerceService" class="com.searcher.service.EcommerceServiceImp">
        <beans:property name="ecommerceDAO" ref="ecommerceDAO">
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Image -->
    <beans:bean id="imageDAO" class="com.searcher.dao.ImageImp">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="imageService" class="com.searcher.service.ImageServiceImp">
        <beans:property name="imageDAO" ref="imageDAO">
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Product -->
    <beans:bean id="productDAO" class="com.searcher.dao.ProductImp">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="productService" class="com.searcher.service.ProductServiceImp">
        <beans:property name="productDAO" ref="productDAO">
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- ProductRequest -->
    <beans:bean id="productRequestDAO" class="com.searcher.dao.ProductRequestImp">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="productRequestService"
        class="com.searcher.service.ProductRequestServiceImp">
        <beans:property name="productRequestDAO" ref="productRequestDAO">
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Request -->
    <beans:bean id="requestDAO" class="com.searcher.dao.RequestImp">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="requestService" class="com.searcher.service.RequestServiceImp">
        <beans:property name="requestDAO" ref="requestDAO">
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Seller -->
    <beans:bean id="sellerDAO" class="com.searcher.dao.SellerImp">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="sellerService" class="com.searcher.service.SellerServiceImp">
        <beans:property name="sellerDAO" ref="sellerDAO">
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- User -->
    <beans:bean id="userDAO" class="com.searcher.dao.UserImp">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="userService" class="com.searcher.service.UserServiceImp">
        <beans:property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO">
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.searcher." />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Searcher</groupId>
    <artifactId>Searcher</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <!-- Build -->
    <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Maybe you should add a tag `@Autowired` above the `private EcommerceService ecommerceService;` in `MainSearcherController` ? Otherwise, your controller cannot the ecommerce service. See [Autowiring in servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843690/autowiring-in-servlet)

Comment: @MincongHuang Yes I did it before but I had another error,
I've updated the post and error if you can see it again please

Comment: Ok, I see. So this time, your service has been wired, but the entity throws an error. This is probably due the your setting in your `EcommerceEntity` : annotation `@GeneratedValue` will let hibernate to generate the Id for you. But in the same time, you've given another Id in your controller. So, can you try to disable the line `ecommerceEntity.setId(4564564);` in your main controller ?

Comment: @MincongHuang Why you recommend to disable this annotation, it's highly used with the Hibernate.

Comment: Just for the debug.. But you're right, I'll delete this comment. @RomanC

Comment: @Guyb I don't see a root cause could you include it in the stacktrace? It's *very* important.

Comment: When I tried to remove before the @GeneratedValue it did not work but Now I did it again and it worked. very weird

Comment: @Roman C Now it works out, the question now is how to add Auto-ID without it interfere.

Comment: That's another question @Guyb

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: Okay, I'll ask another question you are right

Comment: Hi, @Guyb. Do you mind that I provide my answer then you accept it ?

Comment: @MincongHuang Yes sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### NullPointerException

The first exception `NullPointerException` is due to the reference assignment problem. The service class `EcommerceService` wasn't recognized by the controller.

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.searcher.controller.MainSearcherController.helloWorld(MainSearcherController.java:46)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Adding a tag `@Autowired` in `MainSearcherController` can resolve this problem.

```
@Autowired
private EcommerceService ecommerceService;
```

#### PersistentObjectException

The second exception `PersistentObjectException` is due the identifier conflict in Hibernate. `EcommerceEntity` uses annotation `@GeneratedValue`. This tag will let hibernate to generate the Id for you, but in the same time, you've given another Id in your controller:

```
ecommerceEntity.setId(4564564);
```

So Hibernate don't know what to do. Since `@GeneratedValue` is highly used with the Hibernate, the solution is to disable the ID setter. For more detail, you can check: [Stack Overflow • org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist - with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636091/org-hibernate-persistentobjectexception-detached-entity-passed-to-persist-wit).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to persist the entity which is already persist in the table.

also you've given id as sequence generator but setting id in the model object.

Did you get this exception on your second run?

To fix this,

1.don't set id 
2.if you're doing update use method saveOrUpdate

Comment: so wich function i should use to add new row? and saveOrUpdate without new ID?

Answer (score 0):

The error is   `detached entity passed to persist: com.searcher.entity.EcommerceEntity`

It means that you're trying to update an entity of `EcommerceEntity` which is detached from the current **persistence context**. 
In order to update this entity you've to use `merge()` method.

```
@Override
public void edit(EcommerceEntity eCommerce) {
    this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(eCommerce);
    logger.info("EcommerceEntity updated successfully, EcommerceEntity Details="+eCommerce);
}
```

**[More info](http://what-when-how.com/hibernate/working-with-objects-hibernate/) :**

- Modifying the item after the Session is closed has no effect on its persistent representation in the database. As soon as the persistence context is closed, item becomes a detached instance.
- If you want to save modifications you made to a detached object, you have to either reattach or merge it.

Hope this helps.